# Shell Script - Creating Process Menu Based on Users Online

Tags: bash, shell, menu

I have never coded a shell script before, and could use some help. I need to make a menu, with each option being the users online. And from this menu, I can choose a user and see his processes. I cannot figure out how to make a menu from the users though.

```
echo Users Online
who > users.txt
cut -c1-6 users.txt > usernames.txt
```

This puts all 6 characters of a username into a text file, each user to a line. This is where I am stuck. I need to make each user an option to select in my script like so:

```
Users:
1) user1
2) user2
3) user3
```

The program takes in a number based on the user whose processes you want to check. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at bash's `select` command:

```
select foo in $(users); do echo "$foo selected"; done
```

See: `help select`

Comment: To change your prompt when you enter an option. Use PS3(Prompt String 3) environment variable. Just before the select do `PS3='Enter your choice:'` To persist the env var value for subsequent child processes(shells) export it as `export PS3='Enter your choice:'`

Comment: That select command looks awesome! I just tried it however, and keep getting "select: not found" This is a .sh file, but I am not sure if I am able to use the select command. Other commands like grep, ps, and who all work though.

Comment: `select` is a bash shell builtin, Note: bash is different from sh, bash is the superset of sh i.e all featuers of sh is present in bash. bash=bourne again shell, sh=original bourne shell. bash has all features of sh plus many more, 1 of them being `select`

Comment: you can change the shell interpreter by having the 1st line as `#!/bin/bash` or execute using bash `bash script_filename`. Use the case statement if u compulsorily need to use sh.